# Is there a way to measure the angle of the corner of the wall by using point cloud?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, point-clouds

I am a civil engineering student, but my thesis is concerned with the point cloud. I have little knowledge about this stuff, and I am still learning about it.

What I want to know is by using point cloud (laser scanner) is there a method to detect the angle between two walls (like checking if it's 90 degrees or not)? I am using Matlab for programming. Here is an example point cloud image.

[image]

Comment: I think matlab's pcfitplane function suffice your requirement ( https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/pcfitplane.html). You can find your target plane using it. Afterward , inner producting each plane's normal vector will give you the angle.

Comment: Thank u so much :D I will try that.